# Who bid it first? A problem tracking the contents of lists of lists

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I am working on a turn taking card game with bidding (1Club - 1Spade - 1NoTrump, etc.). I want to identify a player called the **"declarer"** which is the player on the partnership that ends up the declaring side who first named the denomination of the final contract.

I can get my code to properly police (for legality) and track (using append) the entire auction. After I go through a screening process to limit user input to legal actions, I arrive at:

```
dealer_call = input(dealer + " bids: ")
```

and

```
auction.append(dealer + ": " + dealer_call)
```

(dealer is a reference to a particular player traditionally identified by direction (NESW) of his or her seat at the table; auction is a list of lists that associates a call with a player and records the calls history)

Eventually we arrive at the termination of the bidding phase of the game

```
 if passes == 3:
  contract = (last_bid)
  print("The auction period is ended. The contract is " + contract + " by " + declaring_side)
```

(declaring_side is a reflection of the fact that it is a partnership game and North-South are partners and East-West are partners)

One player in the partnership is named the Declarer and that is determined by examining the contract, and determining which partner first named the denomination of the contract. I can pull out the denomination of the final contract using

```
denomination = (contract[1])
```

where **(contract[0])** is an integer denoting how many tricks must be taken by the declaring side.  For example a final contract may = 4H.

So my code above would grab the second item in the last bid (for example 4H where denomination = H).

And I can manually scan the auction and use human hardware to assign the Declarer role.

```
declarer = input("The Declarer is: ")
```

However, I strongly believe that this should be trackable/capable of being automated but my efforts so far have been stymied.

(I have attempted to frame this question so that a knowledge of the rules of contract bridge is not required to produce an answer. I realize I may have failed.)

So far I have tried to use the **contract[1]** and the "in" auction values to isolate the first player in a partnership to name a denomination. I am afraid that, as usual, I am making this far more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre]. Instead of pointing us at individual lines of code, please try to provide adequate context: enough of the code so that we can understand, for example, how bids are currently structured and tracked. You say, for example, that you can "manually scan the auction". But you have not shown us any code related to "the auction", only the last bid. Is there an actual varaible somewhere that remembers all the bids in the auction? Does it have any kind of internal structure? You say "and track (using append) the entire auction" - append **to what**?

Comment: auction = []  {auction starts as an empty list and gets populated as we roll through loops}  
    dealer_call = input(dealer + " bids: ")
    print(dealer_call)
    auction.append(dealer + ": " + dealer_call)

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a cool project!
It is a bit hard to follow all the details, but if I understand it right, all you need is to find out who in the partnership first bid on the denomination?
So after the auction you can easily find the denomination it sounds like, as in the `denomination = contract[1]`. And you also have the `declaring_side` variable.

A simple way for clarity would then be to have one or two dictionaries, one for each partnership or single dict with a tuple, here is example with two:

```
from collections import defaultdict
NS_first_bidder = defaultdict(string)
EW_first_bidder = defaultdict(string)
```

Then after each bid you can check the dict to see if the denomination has been bid already and update the dict if not, say `bid` is the tricks and denomination:

```
if not NS_first_bidder[bid[1]]:
      NS_first_bidder[bid[1]] = bidding_partner
```

Then at the end of the auction you can just call the dict for denominator and the partnership:

```
declarer = NS_first_bidder[denominator]
```

It can be done in so many ways, it might be easier to have partnerships and players as binary, so, that NS = 0, EW = 1, N = 00, S = 01, E = 10, W = 11.

Then you could combine many things conveniently into tuples and have easy indexing.

Just my thoughts!

Comment: I ended up just using a new variable to hold the first bidder concept.  { if dealer_call[1] not in dealer_third_denomination:
        dealer_third_denomination = dealer_call[1]
        dealer_third_declarer = dealer}  but I thank you for your suggestion which set me on the right path.  Where can I read about the advantages of defaultdict?  Thanks again so much.

Comment: You’re welcome, I’m glad it worked out :) defauldict is a convenience type, mostly like a normal dictionary, except it does not give key error if the key is not present and you try and call it. Instead it returns the default value of the data type, so for string that would be an empty string. It often makes coding and checking a dict easier.

Comment: dealer = "N"
third = "S"
passes = 0
third_bid = ""
dealer_third_bids = []
while passes < 2:
  dealer_bid = input("Dealer bids: ")
  if dealer_bid == "P":
    passes = passes + 1
  if dealer_bid != "P" and dealer_bid[1] not in dealer_third_bids:
    dealer_third_bids.append(dealer_bid[1])
    declarer = dealer
  third_bid = input("Third bids: ")
  if third_bid == "P":
    passes = passes + 1
  if third_bid != "P" and third_bid[1] not in dealer_third_bids:
    dealer_third_bids.append(third_bid[1])
    declarer = third
print(dealer_third_bids)
print(declarer)